# Is the Frattini subgroup a normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, frattini-subgroup

Ive been trying to attack this question from different point of view but i cant make it. Basicly I started thinking that Frattini was not normal, i was trying to get a counterexample but all the groups I try failed.

Now I am convinced that The Frattini subgroup is normal but i cant prove it.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: The Frattini subgroup is always normal. See here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini_subgroup , for a proof try Wikiproof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Frattini subgroup is the intersection of all maximal subgroups (if there aren't any, it is the whole group). Now, if $M$ is maximal in $G$ then also any conjugate $M^g$ is maximal in $G$. Can you prove that first and then prove your post?

Comment: Ok, I will try that way

Comment: Yes you should display some trying of your own, rather than just posting your question. This is how it works on StackExchange :-).

Comment: I didnt know it!  thanks for the advise! I was thinking to put some of my efforts but it was a lot of messy ideas! and I do not know which one to choose.

Comment: Well I think that you give me the essential clue, it is interesting what is happening!, maybe the maximal groups are not normal but they will switch among them when you apply conjugation! (Correct me if I am wrong). My proof was: Consider a subgroup $S$ containing $M^g$, then if a apply the inverse of the conjugation I get that $S^{g^{-1}}$ contains $M$, hence the first is $M$ or $G$, then applying the conjugation again one see that $S$ is $M^g$ or $G$. Of course here I am using that the conjugation is a bijection. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, well done. So, if $x \in \Phi(G)$ and $g \in G$ with $x^g \notin \Phi(G)$, then $x^g \notin M$ for some maximal subgroup $M$. Hence, $x \notin M^{g^{-1}}$, contradicting $M^{g^{-1}}$ being also maximal (as you showed).

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the help!